# forkJoin depending on another response in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, fork-join, switchmap

I have a `switchMap` and then a `forkJoin` but one of these calls depends on another one

```
this.route.paramMap
        .pipe(
          switchMap((params) => {
            let id = parseInt(params.get('id'));
            return forkJoin({
              tableDataDetail: this.tblService.getTableDataDetail(id),
              comboDetails: this.tblService.getUserComboDetails(// the id from the response of tableDataDetail),
            });
          })
        )
        .subscribe(
          ({ tableDataDetail, comboDetails }) => {
            this.data = tableDataDetail;
            this.comboDetails = comboDetails;   
          }
        )
```

as you can see, I need as params of the getUserComboDetails() service, a field from the response of the other one service (that is the tableDetailId). How can I do this in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if one obs need values from another you need use switchMap again

```
this.route.paramMap
  .pipe(
    switchMap(params => {
      let id = parseInt(params.get("id"));
      return this.tblService.getTableDataDetail(id).pipe(
        switchMap(tableDataDetail => {
          return this.tblService
            .getUserComboDetails(tableDataDetail.id)
            .pipe(
              map(details => ({
                tableDataDetail: tableDataDetail,
                comboDetails: details
              }))
            );
        })
      );
    })
  )
```

NOTE: You can in map, instead return an object return an array

```
this.route.paramMap.pipe(
      ...
                map(details=>([tableDataDetail,details]
                )
              )
           }
        )
      }))
```

So, you can, when subscribe use [destructuring](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html#destructuring)

```
   ....subscribe(res=>{
        [this.data,this.comboDetails]=res;
       })
```

**Update** I make [a stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kw8539?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) and corrected typo syntax -missing some `{` or `)`

Comment: I tried, but i get 'return' doesn't exists in type 'OperatorFunction<unknown, unknown>'

Comment: I just updated adding a stackblitz and corrected the missing bracket